# install gcc4.0 on mac os x 10.8

Tags: python, macos, gcc

I am trying to read and learn the pytho2.5.6 source code, and try to recompile the code everytime i make some change on it.

But it doesn't seem to work when I comile the source code via the following commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/somewhere/that/don't/messup/myenv/
make
```

After `make`, the console just show errors like this:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
```

I search the google , and it seems like the gcc(4.2.1) that i am using is not compatiable with the python2.5.6.

some info of my sys:

```
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Xcode 4.6.2(installed via the xcode command cline tool )
python2.5.6 source code(download from python.org)
```

I have try some solutions like these:

1.download diff python code version , like 2.5.4, and do the steps again.

2.after `configure`,modify the Makefile,and remove the `--Wno-long-double`,but new errors showed like below:

```
        ➜  Python-2.5.6  make
        gcc -c -fno-strict-aliasing -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/mactoolboxglue.o Python/mactoolboxglue.c
        In file included from Include/Python.h:57,
                         from Python/mactoolboxglue.c:26:
        Include/pyport.h:547: warning: ‘struct winsize’ declared inside parameter list
        Include/pyport.h:547: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
        Include/pyport.h:548: warning: ‘struct winsize’ declared inside parameter list
        In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:67,
                         from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                         from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:18,
                         from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:20,
                         from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:18,
                         from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20,
                         from Include/pymactoolbox.h:10,
                         from Python/mactoolboxglue.c:27:
        /usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:109:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
        In file included from Python/mactoolboxglue.c:27:
       .......
       Python/mactoolboxglue.c: In function ‘MediaObj_Convert’:
       Python/mactoolboxglue.c:431: error: ‘cobj’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       Python/mactoolboxglue.c:431: error: too many arguments to function ‘PyMacGluePtr_MediaObj_Convert’
       make: *** [Python/mactoolboxglue.o] Error 1
```

So, i wonder if there are some way to intall gcc4.0 manually?

PS:the reason why i use python2.5.6 is because i read a book called  which is written in chinese.Or maybe the best solution is to read the 2.7 source code =.=....hmmm.....

Comment: Python 2.5 is seriously out of date.  If you want to stick with 2.x, fine, but at least use the latest 2.7.x instead.  Likewise, GCC 4.2 and 4.0 are ancient; try 4.6 or newer since you're just starting out.

Comment: @JohnZwinck , thanks~ i finally give up to install the gcc4.0. I recently install the gcc4.7 via homebrew.